# How to remove alias of existing stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have restored an old database. It has many stored procedures, those are starting with the alias name. For example (`xxx.sp_test`)

How can I remove those aliases in a single shot? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean schema name instead of "alias".  You cannot remove the schema from schema-scoped objects like stored procedures, but you can transfer objects to a different schema, such as from `xxx` to `dbo`, so that 2-part name for a proc becomes `dbo.sp_test`.  This is done using `ALTER SCHEMA`:

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER xxx.sp_test;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER [' + SysSchemas.Name + '].[' + DbObjects.Name + '];'
FROM sys.Objects DbObjects
INNER JOIN sys.Schemas SysSchemas ON DbObjects.schema_id = SysSchemas.schema_id
WHERE SysSchemas.Name = 'xxx'
AND (DbObjects.Type IN ('U', 'P', 'V'))
```

this was I am looking for..